# How to get the last occurrence of lines between two patterns from a file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a log file which reports on the output of a process, I'd like to extract all lines from between the last occurrence of two patterns.

The patterns will be along the lines of;

```
Summary process started at <datestring>
```

and

```
Summary process finished at <datestring> with return code <num>
```

There will be several instances of these patterns throughout the file, along with a lot of other information. I'd like to print the only the last occurrence.

I know that I can use:

```shell
sed -n '/StartPattern/,/EndPattern/p' FileName
```

to get lines between the patterns, but not sure how to get the *last* instance.

`sed` or `awk` solutions would be fine.

**Edit:**
I've not been clear at all about the behaviour that I want when multiple `StartPatterns` appear with no `EndPattern`, or if there's no `EndPattern` before the end of file, after detecting a `StartPattern`.

- For multiple `StartPattern`s with missing `EndPattern`, I'd only like lines from the last `StartPattern` to the `EndPattern`.
- For a `StartPattern` which reaches the `EOF` without an `EndPattern`, I'd like everything up to the `EOF`, followed by a warning that `EOF` was reached prematurely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always do:

```
tac < fileName | sed  '/EndPattern/,$!d;/StartPattern/q' | tac
```

If your system doesn't have GNU `tac`, you may be able to use `tail -r` instead.

You can also do it like:

```
awk '
  inside {
    text = text $0 RS
    if (/EndPattern/) inside=0
    next
  }
  /StartPattern/ {
    inside = 1
    text = $0 RS
  }
  END {printf "%s", text}' < filename
```

But that means reading the whole file.

Note that it may give different results if there's another `StartPattern` in between a `StartPattern` and the next `EndPattern` or if the last `StartPattern` does not have an ending `EndPattern` or if there are lines matching both `StartPattern` and `EndPattern`.

```
awk '
  /StartPattern/ {
    inside = 1
    text = ""
  }
  inside {text = text $0 RS}
  /EndPattern/ {inside = 0} 
  END {printf "%s", text}' < filename
```

Would make it behave more like the `tac+sed+tac` approach (except for the unclosed trailing `StartPattern` case).

That last one seems to be the closest to your edited requirements. To add the warning would simply be:

```
awk '
  /StartPattern/ {
    inside = 1
    text = ""
  }
  inside {text = text $0 RS}
  /EndPattern/ {inside = 0} 
  END {
    printf "%s", text
    if (inside)
      print "Warning: EOF reached without seeing the end pattern" > "/dev/stderr"
  }' < filename
```

To avoid reading the whole file:

```
tac < filename | awk '
  /StartPattern/ {
    printf "%s", $0 RS text
    if (!inside)
      print "Warning: EOF reached without seeing the end pattern" > "/dev/stderr"
    exit
  }
  /EndPattern/ {inside = 1; text = ""}
  {text = $0 RS text}'
```

Portability note: for `/dev/stderr`, you need either a system with such a special file (beware that on Linux if stderr is open on a seekable file that will write the text at the beginning of the file instead of the current position within the file) or an `awk` implementation that emulates it like `gawk`, `mawk` or busybox `awk` (those work around the Linux issue mentioned above).

On other systems, you can replace `print ... > "/dev/stderr"` with `print ... | "cat>&2"`.

Comment: `But that means reading the whole file`. Doesn't tac need to read the whole file?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation of behaviour. I've realised that my question was vague around expected behaviour in unusual cases, so have edited for clarity. You have my +1 already though. The file is unlikely to be huge, so reading it all won't be a problem.

Comment: @Arronical, see edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can use GNU `sed` like so

```
sed '/START/{:1;$!{/END/!{N;b1};h}};${x;p};d' file
```

Just overwrites the hold space every occurrence of the full multiline pattern. Prints it at the end of the file.

This will provide consistent behaviour such as

- Both START and END are on the same line, will match line.
- Multiple STARTs after the initial START, will match all until END
- Will not print match if there is no END, will print last occurrence of full START to END

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation of behaviour. I've realised that my question was vague around expected behaviour in unusual cases, so have edited for clarity. You have my +1 already though.

Comment: (note that you can ping editors with `@...` even if it doesn't offer you completion) GNU specific: `}` not preceded by `;`, labels followed by something, `}` followed by something. The portable equivalent would be `sed -e '/START/{:1' -e '$!{/END/!{N;b1' -e '}' -e 'h;}' -e '}' -e '${x;p;}' -e d` (or use separate lines instead of additional `-e`s.

Comment: Ah right, didn't know you can ping editor, thanks. I've deleted my comment from your answer. Thanks for the posix version as well.

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed`, another solution could be (with variables `P1`/`P2` as start/end patterns) :

```
sed -n "/${P1}/,/${P2}/H; /${P1}/h; \${g;p}"
```

The main differences with @Stéphane Chazelas solution, is that here :

- if multiple STARTs before last END/EOF, we display from last START till last END/EOF.
- any END on same line than START is ignored
- last END in last input line is supported
- if no END after last START, we print from last START till EOF

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with awk:

```
awk '/EndPattern/ {recording=0}  recording>0 {buffer=buffer $0 "\n"}  /StartPattern/ {recording+=1; buffer=""}  END {printf "%s", buffer; if(recording>0) {print "WARNING: missing EndPattern" > "/dev/stderr"}}'
```

So, for the following input:

```
1
StartPattern
2
3
EndPattern
4
5
StartPattern
6
7
EndPattern
8
```

You would get the following output:

```
6
7
```

Please replace StartPattern by ^StartPattern$ if you want an exact line match, same for EndPattern. Also replace recording+=1 by recording=1 if you want to ignore nested patterns.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that as it is currently written, the answer is difficult to understand. You may want to split it into a block containing just the program, then your input example as it would appear in a text file, and then the resulting output.