# sed script to print lines between the last occurence of a pattern and an empty line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to use sed to print the text between the last occurrence of a pattern and an empty line.  For example, in the following file:

```
$ cat file
pattern
1
2
3


pattern
4
5


pattern
6
7
8
9


10
11
```

I want to print only

```
6
7
8
9
```

I tried `sed '/pattern/{:1;$!{/^$/!{N;b1};h}};${x;p};d' file` from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289654/353628), but it does not work.

Edit: This almost works:

```
$ sed -n -e '/pattern/ {n; :a; $!{/\n$/!{N;ba};h} }; $ { x;p }' file
6
7
8
9
```

How can one delete the empty line at the end?

Edit2: Here is a solution that works:

```
$sed '/pattern/{:1;$!{/\n$/!{N;b1};h}};${x;s/pattern\n//;s/\n$//;p};d' file
6
7
8
9
```

Edit3: This is even better:

```
$sed '/pattern/{:1;$!{/\n$/!{N;b1};s///;h}};${x;s/pattern\n//;p};d' file
```

Comment: I must admit I don't fully understand the linked answer, but I think what you're missing is that `/END/` is matched against the *accumulated* lines in the pattern space, rather than the current line. So try setting `/END/` as `/\n$/` rather than `/^$/`

Comment: Thanks!  This almost works!  It still prints an empty line at the end.  Do you know how to delete it?

Comment: I can't see an *elegant* way to do it - the `/END/` has to get pulled into the pattern space in order to match it. You could always just substitute it away - either before pushing the pattern space into the hold buffer (`s/\n$//;h`) or after swapping it back out with (`x;s/\n$//`)

Comment: Thanks! That works.

Comment: ... if you do the substitution before the `h` you can abbreviate it to `s///;h` (the empty pattern `//` re-uses the earlier `/\n$/`)

Comment: Thanks, this is more clear.  Is there also a way to not put the pattern in the hold space so that I don't have to delete it later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the stream editor`sed`, we detect the pattern record and from there on skip the line and loop until the next empty line is found. Till that time accumulate the records in the pattern space and after looping overwrite the contents of hold space with the pattern space's. This happens afresh for each pattern... empty line block. At the end of file, retrieve the contents of hold and print them if nonempty.

```
$ sed -ne '
  /pattern/{
    $d;n
    :loop
      s/\n$//;tdone
      $bdone;N
    bloop
    :done
    x
  }
  ${x;/./p;}
' file
6
7
8
9
```

---

The most. natural fit for such range like problems is the line editor **ed**

```
ed -s file <<\eof
a

.
?pattern?+1;/^$/-1p
Q
eof
```

---

Another way using the GNU sed editor is to collect chunks in the hold space using the range operator.

```
sed -e '
  /pattern/,/^$/!ba
  /./!ba
  H;/pattern/{z;x;}
  :a
  $!d;x;s/.//
' file
```

---

We can use the GNU sed editor in slurp mode and use the greediness of regexes to reach the last instance of pattern

```
sed -Ez '
  s/.*pattern\n(([^\n]+\n)+)(\n.*)?/\1/
' file
```

---

Below is the sed equivalent of the range operator in perl. The array @A functions as the catchment area of block lines.

```
perl -ne 'next unless
  my $e = /pattern/ .. /^$/;
  @A = $e == 1 ? ()
     :   /./   ? (@A, $_)
     :            @A;
  }{print @A;
' file
```

Comment: Thanks!  Really nice scripts.  You are a sed virtuoso.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/pattern/,/^$/ { arr[NR]=$0; if (/pattern/) line1=NR; if (/^$/) line2=NR}END{ if (line1) for(i=++line1;i<line2;i++) print arr[i]}' file
```

`/pattern/,/^$/` will get lines between pattern and empty line.

Then `if (/pattern/) line1=NR` gives record number of last line where pattern is found. `if (/^$/) line2=NR` gives number of last empty line *after pattern is found*.

At last a for loop between two records returns expected output.

This will fail if there aren't two lines between pattern and the next blank line, if pattern is not in the file, or if there isn't a blank line beyond pattern. (Taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647369/469418))

Comment: you can write `awk '
/^pattern/,/^$/{ buf= (buf==""?"":buf (NF?ORS:"")) $0 }
/^pattern/{ buf="" }
END{ if(buf!="") print buf }' infile`,  and of course one can change `NF` to `/^$/` there to match an empty line instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the [previous ed solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647338/117549) could be extended to solve this as well:

```
printf '%s\n' '?pattern?+1' '. +1,/^$/ -1 p' | ed -s file
```

This sends two commands to `ed`:

- `?pattern?+1` -- search backwards from the end of the file for pattern, then move ahead one line from that match; this prints that line
- `. +1,/^$/ -1 p` -- from the next line (current plus 1) through the line before the next blank line (`/^$/ -1`), print those lines

This will fail if there aren't two lines between `pattern` and the next blank line, if `pattern` is not in the file, or if there isn't a blank line beyond `pattern`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably easiest with `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS='' -F '\n' '$1 ~ /pattern/ { hold = $0 } END { if (hold != "") print hold }' file | sed 1d
6
7
8
9
```

This uses `awk` with an empty input record separator, `RS`, which puts `awk` in "paragraph reading mode", which means that we will get a whole paragraph at a time in `$0`.  I'm also using `-F '\n'` which means that each line in the paragraph will be a separate field, so `$1` is the first line of the paragraph.

The code tests whether the regular expression `pattern` matches in the first line of the paragraph.  If is, it keeps hold of the paragraph in the variable `hold`.

At the end, if `hold` is non-empty, it is printed.

`sed` is used to remove the first line of the output (the line matching `pattern`).

To use a shell variable, `$pattern`, in place of a static pattern:

```bsh
pattern=$pattern awk -v RS='' -F '\n' '$1 ~ ENVIRON["pattern"] { hold = $0 } END { if (hold != "") print hold }' file | sed 1d
```

Comment: you can write `awk -v RS='' '
/^pattern/ { sub(/[^\n]*\n/, ""); buf=$0 }
END { if (buf!="") print buf }' infile`, so no need add an extra `sed` deletion.